# How much current can I draw from a battery?

Tags: batteries

I would like to build a portable bluetooth speaker and I would like to know how much current I can draw from a [battery like this?](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/4000867020574.html?spm=2114.12010612.8148356.20.6da857e5XiCAeZ)

The battery is rated on 3.7V and I want to supply [this amplifier with a step up dc dc converter.](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32997202465.html) The amplifier suggests 3A 12V power supply.

Comment: Please provide proper believable data sheet links and not aliexpress links

Comment: Done Thank you :)

Comment: Here is the datasheet of the battery

https://www.lithium-polymer-battery.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/LP543450_3.7V_1000mAh.pdf

Comment: So, if you read that data sheet, what does it tell you about the maximum current?

Comment: It depends on what the battery specification says, I would say that you cannot trust a manufacturer if they have not specified what the levels are and at which operation conditions

Comment: it says 1000 mA but my question is if I can draw more than that somehow (and of course if it is safe to do so)...

Comment: @matthewg - Hi, you said: "Here is the datasheet of the battery https://www.lithium-polymer-battery.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/LP543450_3.7V_1000mAh.pdf " but I see no evidence that datasheet applies to the AliExpress battery you linked. The claimed manufacturer from Aliexpress is "DEAH" and from the datasheet is "LiPol Battery Co., Ltd - China". Note that "543450" is not a battery part number, it's just the size. There are many manufacturers of batteries in that size. My point is that, while some specs of same size batteries *may* be *similar*, you can't rely totally on that datasheet.

Comment: So according to my requirements, a 18650 battery should be fine right?

Comment: Do you have a fire extinguisher handy?  Because LiIon batteries are notorious for catching fire if mistreated.  Overloading the battery isn't really a good idea.

Comment: So what type of battery should I use for my project?

Comment: Ali Express is blocked on my PC. Please add specifications for the battery you want to use.

Answer (score 3):

From the battery specification that you posted it says that the maximum continuous discharging current is 1000mA. Or 1A if you convert the units. So for safe use of the battery and safety to yourself you would not want to exceed this amount.

You were asking about using a boost converter to increase the battery voltage to 12V. A well designed boost converter would be able to achieve an efficiency of say 85%. This means that:

Power_Out = 0.85 * Power_In

Power_In = Vbat * 1A max = 3.7V * 1A = 3.7W max.

Power_Out = 0.85 * 3.7W = 3.14W max.

Current_Out = 3.14W max / 12V = 0.26A max.

This means that you must not place a load on the boost converter of more than 260mA in order to stay within the safe operational zone of the battery.

Answer (score 1):

After commenting about it, I revise my answer. For your battery which is of type LP543450 / 544350, there are different datasheets which state different things. I summurize it to 2 options:

**Option 1:**
[Specification1](https://www.lipobattery.us/1000mah-lipo-battery-lp543450-3-7v-1000mah-3-7wh/)

According to this variant:
Standard discharge current: 0.2A
Max discharging current: 1.9A(2x charge current)
Max impulse discharge current: 4A
Max charge current: 950mA

**Option 2:**
[Specification2](https://www.lipolbattery.com/LiPo-Battery-Datahseet/LiPo_Battery_LP543450_3.7V_1000mAh.pdf)

Max charge current: 500mA
Max discharge current: 1000mA.

**Result:**
According to me its safe to assume 500mA of charging current and 950mA of discharge current.

Comment: And what exactly is rapid drain. What is the difference from discharging current?

Comment: Rapid drain is draining 1.3A for a short time after which you have to return to the 0.52A maximum.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help... :)

Comment: After you test my answer, please select it as the solution and upvote it.

Comment: @CFCBazar - Hi, (a) You don't mean "*2600A/h*" :-) (b) Why are you including (IMHO) potentially confusing details about a 2600 mAh 18650 cell into the answer, when the question is about a totally different cell?! If you really want to include details of that different cell type, I suggest you make it very clear in the text that you are *not* giving any numbers that apply to the type of cell in the question - but in that case, how do they help the OP? See what I mean? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry about the A/h, that's a typo. The specification and example I gave is valid for his battery. I gave an average example of an 18650 3.7V Li-IOn battery, but the capacity and current drain ration for his are about the same. Meaning for a 1.1A/h battery, he will get 1.1A impulse current and 0.55A rapid drain and less continuous drain. Also noted that 1A is the maximum he drain and gave the example with a 2.6A/h battery to make it clear how to calculate it, where for the big battery the drain is 0.52A, so for smaller one it would be less, as well as the rapid current drain.

Comment: @CFCBazar - Hi, Thanks for fixing the typo. Whilst I still disagree about other details (e.g. allowed discharge rates can be *very* different between a typical 18650 Li-Ion cell  in your answer and Li-Po cells like the OP's so I don't think the comparison is particularly helpful) I will just say that I think your recent comment is an improvement over what is currently in the answer, as the comment at least mentions that idea of "ratio[n]" changes in the numbers for a smaller cell. Anyway, I don't believe we will have a "meeting of minds" so I'll stop here. Sincere thanks for replying anyway.

Comment: I don't mind positive critics, I just hate haters. As soon as I go back, I will check the datsheet for the LiPo and make any changes if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Try a LiPo battery as used in Drones & RC cars.  They're not the same thing as the batteries used in cellphones & computers.  Designed to output MUCH higher currents.
They also have built-in safety circuits, making it much much harder to blow yourself up   ;)  They're also available in higher output voltages, making your boost-job easier and less taxing.

Example:  https://www.ebay.com/itm/Ovonic-50C-7-4V-5200mAh-2S-Lipo-Battery-for-Traxxas-RC-Car-Truck-Boat-Drone-FPV/183819976582?hash=item2acc863f86:g:oEEAAOSwq2heWNGZ

This one has  50C rated output - Meaning it can source 5200mA * 50 = 260A !    Notice how thick the wires are.

Comment: Good suggestion on a high power battery, but 'they also have built-in safety circuits' is wrong. In fact the batteries used in RC vehicles generally do **not** have any protection circuits built in, in order to supply the greatest amount of power with lightest weight. It is the _user's_ responsibility to add safety circuits as needed (charge protection is usually built into the charger, and discharge protection into the speed controller). The only 'internal' protection that most RC car batteries have is a 'hard' case to prevent physical damage.

Comment: ^^^    I don't drive RC vehicles, but last year I was involved in the design of a drone.  We used standard LiPo "drone" batteries, modified slightly for our purpose.  They were prismatic cells.  They 100% absolutely had a small circuit board inside that provides protection circuitry.    As part of the design, I actually visited one of the major drone battery manufacturers in Asia, and saw every prismatic cell going down the assembly line had this circuitry in it.     I presumed such circuits were in RC car batteries also.    I shouldn't presume, you're right.   ....